# jQuery crashing browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, crash

I'm trying to develop a game using jQuery. it will create some div's dynamically using jQuery and also removing unnecessary div's, but after some time my browser going heavy and using lot of process and getting crashed.

If refresh my page, again I'm able to play the game for some time.

Except this remaining functionality working fine..

What is the problem?
How to solve it?

Comment: How do you expect us to tell you the problem? Can you link us to the game?

Comment: Are you generating more and more intervals? Which will be to much for the browser after some time? 

Do you got an example?

Comment: Can I suggest that you use the HTML5 canvas element for games. Making and destroying lots of divs with javascript is not ideal.

Comment: @Raju Are you removing or hiding unnecessary divs?

Comment: please link us or provide some code

Comment: @Blender It's still under development right now I don't have any server to publish it. It uses some java libraries also. so not possible to post on JavaScript tool sites..

Comment: Is the problem consistent on all browsers?

Comment: @dr jerry yes all browsers same problem

Answer (score 3):

Use something like the web developer and/or firebug add on for FireFox to see what is happening to your HTML live and what JS problems you may be having.

Comment: Just because you don't have any errors doesn't mean your code is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think Chrome Web developer Tools will help u to solve the problem.

open the tool( Ctrl+Shift+J ) -> Profiles -> CPU Profiles

you will find which process( function ) cost too much time. have a try :-)

Comment: so just use Chrome Dev Tools to profile it, if it works well in Chrome, then it may be work well in others too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try display:hidden, if the dom doesn't show up, it won't need the browser to render it.